# How to split or explode string and show values in selectbox

Tags: php, mysql

How to break string values in chunks

```
include 'conn.php';
$query="SELECT defaultvalue FROM meta WHERE fieldid='grade' AND tableid='student'";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value='".$row['defaultvalue']."'>";echo $row['defaultvalue']; echo "</option>";

}
```

its shows like

`I II III IV V VI VII VIII XI X`

I want to show this string value Dropdown
like this

```
<select>
    <option>I</option>
    <option>II</option>
    <option>III</option>
    <option>IV</option>
    <option>V</option>
    etc 
</select>
```

Comment: You're missing the opening `<select>` tag. (And the closing `</select>` too, btw)

Comment: this is example of my code!! i knw select is missing but i want to break this  I II III IV V VI VII VIII XI X

Comment: Once again, googling `php explode string` shows stackoverflow new question page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `<select>` tag. Your updated code as below.

```
<?php 
   include 'conn.php';
    $query="SELECT defaultvalue FROM meta WHERE fieldid='grade' AND tableid='student'";
    $result= mysqli_query($con,$query);
    echo '<select>';
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

        echo "<option value='".$row['defaultvalue']."'>";echo $row['defaultvalue']; echo "</option>";

        }
     echo '</select>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 include 'conn.php';
        $query="SELECT defaultvalue FROM meta WHERE fieldid='grade' AND tableid='student'";
        $result= mysqli_query($con,$query);
        echo "<select>";
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

        echo "<option value='".$row['defaultvalue']."'>".$row['defaultvalue']."</option>";

        }
        echo "</select>;
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing select tag. you should open `select` tag before start of the loop

```
include 'conn.php';
    $query="SELECT defaultvalue FROM meta WHERE fieldid='grade' AND tableid='student'";
    $result= mysqli_query($con,$query);
    echo "<select>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value='".$row['defaultvalue']."'>".$row['defaultvalue']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
```